# Yii2 file upload is not validating file type

Tags: php, yii

My Model code,

```
public function rules()
{
    return [            
        [['image'], 'safe'],
        ['image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'],
    ];
}
```

Use Apartfrom types,validation message not display document save in database

Answer (score 3):

To validate file type you should use property `$extensions` of FileValidator.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [

            [['image'], 'safe'],
            [['image'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png'],
        ];
    }
```

**Update**

Ok, I've got this. Please check one more time the source link, especially the controller section. To validate your model, you have to use `validate()` function.

Example code:

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

if ($model->file && $model->validate()) {                
    $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
}
```

[Source.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html)

Comment: Use extensions also.Validation message not display

Comment: $fileupload = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
      if(!empty($fileupload))
       {
        $fileupload->saveAs('uploads/' . $fileupload->baseName . '.' . $fileupload->extension);
        $model->image = $fileupload->baseName . '.' . $fileupload->extension;
        $model->save();
       }      
    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('succ', 'Category added successfully');
      return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('/admin/category');

Comment: @Dileep kurane, don't be shy to upvote the answer if it helped you.